# Enumeration<URL> configs.hasMoreElements() gives false

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I am developing a voice-based app in android and facing some problems please see below code,

Java File 1
file = .wav file

```
public static AudioInputStream getAudioInputStream(File file) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    return getAudioInputStreamImpl(file);
}
private static AudioInputStream getAudioInputStreamImpl(Object source) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    GetAudioInputStreamAudioFileReaderAction action = new GetAudioInputStreamAudioFileReaderAction(source);
    doAudioFileReaderIteration(action);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = action.getAudioInputStream();

    if (audioInputStream != null) {
        return audioInputStream;
    }
    throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("format not supported");
}
private static void doAudioFileReaderIteration(AudioFileReaderAction action) throws IOException {
    Iterator audioFileReaders = TAudioConfig.getAudioFileReaders();
    boolean bCompleted = false;

    while (audioFileReaders.hasNext() && !bCompleted) {
        AudioFileReader audioFileReader = (AudioFileReader) audioFileReaders.next();
        bCompleted = action.handleAudioFileReader(audioFileReader);
    }
}
```

Java file 2 (TAudioConfig)

```
public static synchronized Iterator<AudioFileReader> getAudioFileReaders() {
    Iterator<AudioFileReader> it;
    synchronized (TAudioConfig.class) {
        it = getAudioFileReadersImpl().iterator();
    }
    return it;
}
private static synchronized Set<AudioFileReader> getAudioFileReadersImpl() {
    Set<AudioFileReader> set;
    synchronized (TAudioConfig.class) {
        if (sm_audioFileReaders == null) {
            sm_audioFileReaders = new ArraySet();
            registerAudioFileReaders();
        }
        set = sm_audioFileReaders;
    }
    return set;
}
private static void registerAudioFileReaders() {
    TInit.registerClasses(AudioFileReader.class, new C00001());
}
```

Java File 3 (TInit)

```
public static void registerClasses(Class providerClass, ProviderRegistrationAction action) {


    Iterator providers = Service.providers(providerClass);
    if (providers != null) {
        while (providers.hasNext()) {
            try {
                action.register(providers.next());
            } catch (Throwable e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java File 4 (Service)

```
public static Iterator<?> providers(Class<?> cls) {

    String strFullName = "com/example/voiceautomator/AudioFileReader.class";

    Iterator<?> iterator = createInstancesList(strFullName).iterator();
    return iterator;
}
private static List<Object> createInstancesList(String strFullName) {   
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Iterator<?> classNames = createClassNames(strFullName);
    if (classNames != null) {
        while (classNames.hasNext()) {
            String strClassName = (String) classNames.next();
            try {
                Class<?> cls = Class.forName(strClassName, REVERSE_ORDER, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

                providers.add(0, cls.newInstance());
            } catch (Throwable e) {

            }
        }
    }
    return providers;
}
private static Iterator<String> createClassNames(String strFullName) {       
    Set<String> providers = new ArraySet<String>();
    Enumeration<?> configs = null;        
    try {
                    configs =  Service.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResources(strFullName);
    } catch (Throwable e) {

    }
    if (configs != null) {
        while (configs.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL configFileUrl = (URL) configs.nextElement();

            InputStream input = null;
            try {
                input = configFileUrl.openStream();
            } catch (Throwable e2) {


            }
            if (input != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                try {
                    for (String strLine = reader.readLine(); strLine != null; strLine = reader.readLine()) {
                        strLine = strLine.trim();
                        int nPos = strLine.indexOf(35);
                        if (nPos >= 0) {
                            strLine = strLine.substring(0, nPos);
                        }
                        if (strLine.length() > 0) {
                            providers.add(strLine);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e22) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    Iterator<String> iterator = providers.iterator();

    return iterator;
}
```

getClassLoader().getSystemResources in the Java File 4 (Service) gives me TwoEnumerationsInOne and configs.hasMoreElements() gives false so not able to go into while loop.

AudioFileReader.java is included in the package

Please guide me to resolve this issue?

Please don't forget I am working on this code in an android project

Please see the value of configs here

http://capsicumtech.in/Screenshot_1.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be rather surprised if `getSystemResources()` works well on Android. If this project is a dedicated Android project, why not use an XML resource (`res/xml/`), a raw resource (`res/raw/`), or an asset (`assets/`)?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry I am little new in android so not getting what you are saying can you guide me in the same. what do you mean by dedicated Android project?