# this.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResources("strFullName") returns null Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on speech based android app, I got stuck up at a point

```
Enumeration<?> configs =  Service.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResources("com/example/packagename/AudioFileReader.class");
```

Above line gives TwoEnumerationsInOne but

```
if (configs != null) {
        while (configs.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL configFileUrl = (URL) configs.nextElement();

            InputStream input = null;
            try {
                input = configFileUrl.openStream();
            } catch (Throwable e2) {

            }
            if (input != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                try {
                    for (String strLine = reader.readLine(); strLine != null; strLine = reader.readLine()) {
                        strLine = strLine.trim();
                        int nPos = strLine.indexOf(35);
                        if (nPos >= 0) {
                            strLine = strLine.substring(0, nPos);
                        }
                        if (strLine.length() > 0) {
                            providers.add(strLine);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e22) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is configs.hasmoreElements() always gives false so not able to go inside while loop.

AudioFileReader.java file is included in the package.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Friend you are doing something terribly wrong. By any change are you trying to load `AudioFileReader` class

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Kainix yes I want to load AudioFileReader class for audioinputstrem instance

Comment: @njzk2 I am intializing an AudioInputStram for that project needs this part of code

Comment: i don't understand why you are using getSystemResources

Comment: @njzk please check my another question I have explained everything in detail there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725291/enumerationurl-configs-hasmoreelements-gives-false

Comment: @Kainix I have updated my question can yiu help me with this I mean making object of class and all.